# SSRS - Create sparkline from a dataset with multiple fields in columns

Tags: ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I am trying to create a single sparkline from a dataset which contains   multiple fields in different columns of tablix. To explain in details:

I have a tablix with 12 columns. Each column gets value from a different field in the dataset. It means that I have 12 fields in dataset and each goes to one of those 12 columns. The problem is, I am trying to create a sparkline in the 13 column for each row, however, when I create a sparkline it create 12 sparklines. However, I want one sparkline with field values from 1 to 12 months, one after the other.

I am stuck with this since 2 days. Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If processing time is not of an issue, try building a second data set and do a lookup for the sparkline.

Second, you may be able to un-pivot your data and use matrix to build sparkline.

[Table on Top, Matrix below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wz0gC.png)

Comment: Thanks it worked by un-pivoting the data, however, now I have another issue. 0 values doesn't show up on the spark-line. That is if I have 2 values in the row and rest 10 are zero then sparkline is just connecting these two points. I have tried to set an expression in Chart Data > Values like   
=iif((Sum(Fields!Amount.Value)=0),0,Sum(Fields!Amount.Value))  
It also didn't work...Do you have any idea, how to resolve this?

Comment: When you are un-pivoting the data, do the isNULL(column, 0).

Comment: Hi SVZa, I have posted what I want to achieve as a separate question. I would appreciate if you can answer there, as I have explained there in details, what I want to achieve. Here is the new question link, [New Question Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39030451/ssrs-sql-query-to-show-the-zero-value-for-non-existing-records)