# SSRS SQL Query to show the zero value for non existing records

Tags: sql, ssrs-2012

I am using the following query to pull the data for last 11/12 months

```
SELECT [ID]
      ,[Name]  
      ,[Amount]     
FROM DB1 
WHERE [Period] BETWEEN @FromMonth AND @ToMonth  
      AND [Desc] = 'XYZ'
```

What I want to achieve is, some IDs does not have a any record for some periods(month) with no amount. Currently the query doesn't return anything for those combination of names and months where there is no record in DB. It only displays a result if the ID has a certain amount and date in db. However, what I want is that if an ID doesn't have an amount for a month then it should show the amount for that month.

`@FromMonth` and `@ToMonth` are the parameters being passed to the report. I know I can achieve this by pivoting but I don't want to do that. Any hints?

Comment: I'm a little confused by the following statement: `what I want is that if an ID doesn't have an amount for a month then it should show the amount for that month`  Perhaps sample data and expected results would be helpful.

Comment: You need a table or view or piece of SQL that lists all of the months. Then you need to outer join to that table.

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess based on your title, perhaps this is what you're looking for using a `case` statement:

```
select id, name, 
    case when Period between @FromMonth and ToMonth and [Desc] = 'XYZ' 
         then amount 
         else 0 
    end as amount
from db1
```

This will return all `ids` and `names` from `db1`, but only include the `amount` for those records matching your previous `where` criteria.

---

By the way,  I'd typically recommend avoid using `reserved words` as column names (`desc`).

Comment: Thanks for your help sgeddes